# Using Chrome to open a web page as a standalone "application"?

Tags: google-chrome, flag

Is it possible to open a web page as if it were a standalone application using Chrome?

For example, create a chrome shortcut on my desktop and set the command line flags to open up a specific web page, and have the URL/Search and bookmarks bars hidden, and have it so it is not possible to open up new tabs in that window.

I'd want the page to look something like this (this is mspaint'ed):

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: I have an online portal for tracking work items. I would like to be able to open it separately from the rest of my web browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, the command line switch is `--app=http://example.com`

> Specifies that the associated value should be launched in "application" mode.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc&q=kApp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=74